# How to get current values from dataframe to build a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having troubles figuring out how to plug in values from a dataframe into a list.  The dataframe looks like this

```
date        A        B      C        D     
2018-05-25  188.58   35.56  1.66  21.91
```

When I do this:

```
new = stats['A']
print(new)
```

I get this:

```
18    188.58
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

I am looking for a list like this, but how to get the values in there:

```
mylist = [188.58, 35.56, 1.66, 21.91]
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC

```
df
Out[165]: 
         date       A      B     C      D
0  2018-05-25  188.58  35.56  1.66  21.91
df.iloc[0,1:]
Out[166]: 
A    188.58
B     35.56
C      1.66
D     21.91
Name: 0, dtype: object
df.iloc[0,1:].tolist()
Out[167]: [188.58, 35.56, 1.66, 21.91]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `df.values` to create a list of lists with each list containing a row of data.

```
df
         date       A      B     C      D
0  2018-05-25  188.58  35.56  1.66  21.91

df.values.tolist()
[['2018-05-25', 188.58, 35.56, 1.66, 21.91]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample program that can append the values to a list

```
array = np.array([188.58, 35.56, 1.66, 21.91])
date = datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 25)

data_frame = pd.DataFrame({'A': 188.58, 'B': 35.56, 'C': 1.66, 'D': 21.91}, index=pd.DatetimeIndex([date]))

list_ = []

for num in range(0, 4):
    list_.append(float(data_frame.iloc[0, num]))

print(list_)
```

Here is our output:

```
[188.58, 35.56, 1.66, 21.91]
```

We can just run a for loop and then append based on iloc position. We could also do a list comprehension, but I felt as if it'd be more useful to simply show the entire loop in this example.